# How do I insert a script tag in to the top/beginning of head tag?

Tags: javascript, append, native, appendchild

I want to insert a script tag before all the rest of the scripts in the head tag. How would I do that with native javascript?

```
<head>
    //INSERT SCRIPT HERE
     <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="omni-controls.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I use this, it just appends after all the tags in the head tag.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: What's the reasoning for this? It will not change the execution order of the existing scripts.

Comment: Why do you need to insert it at the top? Since it's being dynamically inserted, you can assume the other scripts have already loaded. Therefore, placing it at the top of the `HEAD` tag wouldn't matter.

Comment: If you must, you can use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) although I don't see the point.

Comment: The script I am inserting is jquery and there is a script in the head that requires jquery and I get an error in console say "jquery is not defined" and that script won't load.

Comment: @Justin Then this will not help, you are loading in jQuery too late as the other script has failed to find it and stopped running. Why not just add the script tag in there without javascript?

Comment: @Justin: You should really ask about the actual problem, and not your presumed solution. If your code relies on jQuery, you should load jQuery as part of the page.

Comment: Got it. Let me edit this question and present the actual problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]

head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

Comment: You could explain the code I guess, provide links to docs, description of how it works... I didn't -1, just taking a guess.

Comment: @sachleen: Yeah, that may be it. I think some code like this is effectively self-documenting.

Comment: @user1689607 When a user comes in asking how to put a script at the top of the head because they want it to load before the other two... well, let's just say you should assume they know very little and need explaining/hand-holding ;D

Comment: FYI, this accomplishes what the OP asked for, but doesn't result in anything different than using `appendChild()` because the other scripts have already executed so putting a new one before them vs. after them doesn't change anything.  My guess is that the OP is mistaken about thinking that this will solve a problem for them.

Comment: @TheZ, jfriend00: I'm certain this is likely an *X/Y Problem*. The stubborn part of me likes to answer the direct question, and let them live with the result of not asking about the actual problem.

Comment: @user1689607 Haha, fair enough, I feel like that too some days

Answer (score 6):

Get the `firstChild` of the `<head>`, and then use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

This won't change the order scripts are loaded in though (since you'll be inserting it into the DOM after other scripts have been parsed), so this won't give any significate difference from  just using `appendChild`

Answer (score 5):

```
document.head.insertBefore(script, document.head.firstElementChild);
```