# Cannot insert the meta tag at the beginning of a head

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a script into the beginning of a head in a react app.
The only way I could think of it was adding the following to component did mount:

```
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.insertBefore("<meta  id='test'/>", head.firstElementChild);
    console.log("test");
    console.log(head);
```

which I found here:

[How do I insert a script tag in to the top/beginning of head tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979366/how-do-i-insert-a-script-tag-in-to-the-top-beginning-of-head-tag)

But I cannot see anything inserted into the head.
Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore takes a node

Comment: Let me introduce you to [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

Comment: @NinoFiliu I need to add it to the begining of the head. Can I use it helmet for that?

Comment: @SLaks Thanks but still not sure whats wrong with my code. I am following the same

Comment: You should not add `<script>` tags; instead, load & execute the script directly.

Comment: @SLaks I put script as an example there. Lets say I wanna add meta tag

Comment: Unless you're server-rendering, that won't do anything.

Comment: Only the following tags can be included in the `<head>`: title, style, base, link, meta, script, noscript. None of them has an order that matters when JS starts (except indeed in the case of server-side rendering).

Comment: @NinoFiliu the issue is I am trying to add facbook metatags and as soon as I add them at the begining of a page it works if I append them to the end it does not

Comment: How to inject using `react-helmet` at the top of the  `<head />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertBefore()` takes an `Element`, not a string.

You need to create an `Element` using `document.createElement()`.